# D3JS: is it possible to pass a function which retrieves a value to "transform, translate" property?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to pass a function which retrieves a value or other, depending on some checkings this function does, to the `y` translation in  `.attr("transform", "translate...")` method on d3js.

The point is that it always throw errors on console, such as "garbage trailing" and I want to know if this is possible to do.

This is the line of code I'm having problem with:

```
.attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + "," + ()=> isMobileDevice ? height*1.2 : height + ")")
```

I know i'm doing something wrong here but haven't been able to figure out what it is. Any suggestion will be very appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If `isMobileDevice()` is a function that returns true or false, why not just invoke it with `isMobileDevice()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you are asking but if you want to call a function for the `translate` attribute, you can do it like this:

```
.attr("transform", function(d) {
   var x = someFunction();
   var y = someOtherFunction();

  return  "translate(" + x + "," + y ");"    
});
```